# How can i run multiple command in a one exe file or others?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, command-line, exe

I don't understand if I can describe my question properly. Here I give you details.

I have a python file where I run some website vuln check. this code like:

```
python sitecheck.py k -u https://websitename.com/hello.aspx
```

But now problem is, I have more than 200 websites to run in CMD. Every time I need to open a new command line and execute those python separately.

But now I want to run all of my 200 website python check at a time. Which can open 200 command line/prompt at a time after I run exe or other.

Is there any why to make this possible?

Comment: Do you want to run them all at once or after each other?

Comment: @Axiumin_ yes, At a time.. I think 200 windows task can open at a time... because single website check need 2-10 min so it will be long time for 200 task after one to another. So i wanted to run them all at a time.

Comment: Could you provide the code in `sitecheck.py` please? Thanks!

Comment: look into `multiprocessing` python library

Comment: @Axiumin_ Yes. you can find this code here: https://pastebin.com/jX36mK6s

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this in a notepad and past it into a cmd prompt, to do it, I use rhe samd metbod for eunning multiple pythons at once all the time, but do it from a cmd script because I prefer not to paste the entire thing into the cmd prompt.

```
FOR %_ IN (
"SIte1 url"
"site2 url" "site3 url"
) DO (
  start "%~_" "CMD /cpython sitecheck.py k -u %~_ "
)
```

If you prefer to launch it from a cmd script, just needs the %s doubled:

```
@echo off 
FOR %%_ IN (
"SIte1 url"
"site2 url" "site3 url"
) DO (
  start "%%~_" "CMD /cpython sitecheck.py k -u %%~_ "
)

That will open up N command prompts in parrallel running the python script. (where N is the number of URLs you put in the loop)
```